# Do children who kill animals turn out to be violent?

Tags: psychology, children, violence

It is widely claimed that children who injure or kill animals as children are more likely to exhibit violent behavior as adults, committing domestic violence or murder.  A site dedicated to discussing "killer kids" [describes "cruelty to animals & smaller children" as one of the "warning signs of kids who kill"](http://web.archive.org/web/20110717210411/http://www.violentkids.com/violence_facts.html).

The People for the Ethical Treatment of Animals (PETA), who actually cite some sources, [states that this goes both ways](http://www.peta.org/issues/Companion-Animals/animal-abuse-and-human-abuse-partners-in-crime.aspx):

> Acts of cruelty to animals are not mere indications of a minor personality flaw in the abuser; they are symptomatic of a deep mental disturbance. Research in psychology and criminology shows that people who commit acts of cruelty to animals don’t stop there—many of them move on to their fellow humans. “Murderers ... very often start out by killing and torturing animals as kids,” says Robert K. Ressler, who developed profiles of serial killers for the Federal Bureau of Investigation (FBI).
>
> Studies have shown that violent and aggressive criminals are more likely to have abused animals as children than criminals who are considered non-aggressive. A survey of psychiatric patients who had repeatedly tortured dogs and cats found that all of them had high levels of aggression toward people as well. According to a New South Wales newspaper, a police study in Australia revealed that “100 percent of sexual homicide offenders examined had a history of animal cruelty.” To researchers, a fascination with cruelty to animals is a red flag in the backgrounds of serial killers and rapists. According to the FBI’s Ressler, “These are the kids who never learned it’s wrong to poke out a puppy’s eyes.”

Apparently, even as adults such individuals [are still violent toward animals](http://www.americanhumane.org/interaction/support-the-bond/fact-sheets/animal-abuse-domestic-violence.html).

Is there any evidence of a correlation between childhood violence toward animals and violent behavior as an adult (or vice versa)?

Comment: [Peter Kürten](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_K%C3%BCrten#Early_life) was a rather unsavoury chap that tortured animals as a young child. "Kürten progressed from torturing animals to attacks on people. He committed his first provable murder in 1913, strangling a 10-year-old girl, Christine Klein, during the course of a burglary." Posted as a comment because it's anecdotal. There are an awful lot of these anecdotes however.

Comment: I thought that the claim was that sociopathic, sadistic adults who hurt humans often start by, when they're children, hurting animals.

Comment: @Chris - Isn't that what's being claimed in the question, and alluded to in my comment?

Comment: @boehj - No the claims are different. One claim is that children's hurting/hunting animals predicts sociopathic adulthood, and the other is that sociopathic adulthood predicts hurting/hunting animals as a child. For example, if you were given that "All Athenians are liars": then would being Athenian predict that you're a liar, and/or would being a liar predict that you're an Athenian?

Comment: @Chris: I'm not getting it. Excuse my foggy brain. **Question**: "Do children who kill animals turn out to be violent? [...] It is widely claimed that children who injure or kill animals as children are more likely to exhibit violent behavior as adults, committing domestic violence or murder. [...] is there any evidence of a correlation between childhood violence toward animals and violent behavior as an adult?" **Comment**: 'Peter Kürten was a rather unsavoury chap that tortured animals as a young child. "Kürten progressed from torturing animals to attacks on people.' What's the difference?

Comment: @boehj - Your comment was inline with my claim. My claim isn't quite the same as the OP's. When I started my comment with "I thought that..." I was suggesting a correction to the OP, not to your anecdote.

Comment: @ChrisW: OK. Again, excuse my foggy (long-weekend) brain.

Comment: I think the important question is *why* is the person in question killing said animals, not simply whether they are doing so.

Comment: @ChrisW, boehj:  I'd find proof of either correlation interesting and in the spirit of my question.  I'll edit it make that more clear.  However, all of the claims I found and sourced in my question specifically stated that the correlation went the way I described.  I think I'll go ahead and add some blockquotes too.

Comment: "I think the important question is *why* is the person in question killing said animals" -- Or perhaps, "why not". Someone told me she'd seen a documentary about [Australian history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_massacres_of_Indigenous_Australians) recently.

Comment: @ChrisW Spot on, *why* is the key question. Children who torture animals just to see them suffer, may well move on to people (who are more satisfying in that regard). However, if animal suffering is a by-product of curiosity and not a goal in itself, the kids are just somewhat callous within normal bounds, perhaps just enough for a decent career as a doctor or a bio researcher. My brother was in the latter group -- as a child he liked to catch animals (e.g. snakes, frogs) and figure out how they behave. He'd normally release them, and did not inflict pain on purpose, but many did suffer.

Comment: @Patches - You said: "I know I learned to hunt and fish when I was young, and lots of other kids do too. It seems unlikely that all of us will turn out violent someday." I don't think going hunting with your Pa and torturing a kitten to death are the same thing. I also don't think it's the point made by others in the question. I think it confuses the point of the question. Suggest editing that part out.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79:  Neither do I, but the point of that was to illustrate the fact that the claimants really don't make it clear as to what they mean by violence toward animals.  But if you really think it confuses the question, feel free to edit it out.  I wouldn't mind.

Comment: I may be repeating what some of the others have pointed out, but: 'a police study in Australia revealed that “100 percent of sexual homicide offenders examined had a history of animal cruelty.”' - without a control group this is meaningless. If they define animal cruelty broadly enough, it may be that 100% of non-offenders ALSO have a history of animal cruelty. More realistically, it may be that children who are cruel to animals still only have a tiny chance of becoming adult offenders.

Comment: I wouldn't equate learning how to hunt and fish with someone abusing or being violent towards an animal. Hunting and fishing are skills, and in the end you generally eat what you have killed. You aren't doing it maliciously, or simply to kill and torture/be violent. The kids who are "violent" towards animals are the ones that torture pets, small animals like mice, birds etc..

Comment: They're certainly not talking about hunting and fishing. They are talking about intentional sadism and torturing of animals, without needing to expand or equivocate the definition by saying "meat is murder/torture, period." Shooting the hunted animal, even if you enjoy the process of the hunt and take satisfaction in a successful completion of a task does not map to "cruelty" in the way, say, someone burying stray cats, alive, up to their necks and running them over with a lawnmower, for kicks, would.

Comment: being socialized to hunt/fish is not the same as secretly torturing animals, no predictive value...

Comment: I removed the subthread about hunting that has taken up the bulk of the conversation for the last seven years. I've grown tired of it distracting from the main question, which doesn't yet have a satisfactory answer.

Comment: The millions of people who learn to hunt while they are children pretty clearly shows that killing animals is not a cause to murderous behavior. Rather more believably, psychopathic individuals in the right circumstances gain pleasure from killing animals *and* humans, whether they "started" with one or the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, yes, there's a correlation. Keeping in mind Oddthinking's comment on the value of such non-random samples, this is where most of the correlational data comes from, [e.g.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/10926771.2011.610773):

> A history of childhood cruelty to animals and contemporary patterns of
>   chronic interpersonal aggression has been documented in assaultive incarcerated
>   offenders, perpetrators of sexual homicides, rapists, and child
>   molesters (Felthous, 1980; Felthous & Yudowitz, 1997; Kellert & Felthous,
>   1985; Merz-Perez, Heide, & Silverman, 2001; Ressler, Burgess, & Douglas,
>   1988; Tingle, Barnard, Robbins, Newman, & Hutchinson, 1986), making a
>   case for the potential prognostic value of childhood animal cruelty.

As to what is the ultimate cause however, it's nowhere near as simple as MSalters' answer makes it to be, i.e. [lack of] empathy is not the only cause, although it does [play a role](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27440166):

> animal abuse was negatively associated with affective empathy and national culture

Childhood animal cruelty (CAC) is also correlated with [prior] exposure to interpersonal and animal violence (same source):

> Rural adolescents were more likely to abuse animals and had higher exposure to domestic violence, which (in turn) was associated with more animal abuse.

And as to whether CAC has better predictive value than these other associates... one review says no. Quoting from the first paper:

> In a recent review of research on children who are cruel to animals,
>   McPhedran (2009) concluded that the home environment is generally a better
>   predictor of the development of adult violence than childhood cruelty to
>   animals and we should not infer that animal cruelty leads to other antisocial
>   behaviors throughout development. McPhredran suggested that the context
>   within which cruelty to animals occurs is most likely the common factor, and
>   that the complex nature of abusive home environments and experiences that
>   contribute to behavioral problems and interpersonal violence should be an
>   important target of our interventions.

citing

> McPhedran, S. (2009). Animal abuse, family violence, and child wellbeing: A review. Journal of Family Violence, 24, 41–52.

Alas all review works in this area seem to be of the narrative kind, so the quality of inference (one way or the other) is likely to be biased.

McPhedran's review seems to be talking at some length about what appears to be the New South Wales study that prompted your question, and Oddthinking's comments (on the lack of controls etc.) are reflected in McPhedran's review as:

> Although Gullone and Clarke (2006)
>   contend that there appears to be a greater likelihood that
>   people alleged to have abused animals will engage in
>   offenses against the person when compared to all alleged
>   offenders, they did not specify the order of offending. Thus
>   it cannot be concluded that animal cruelty preceded other
>   offenses.
>   It must also be noted that although 25% of animal abuse
>   offenders committed offenses against the person, this
>   entails that 75% of animal abusers did not commit offenses
>   of that nature. It is acknowledged that offenses may have
>   been committed but not detected by police, but it should
>   also be considered that this appears an insufficient
>   explanation to account for the entire 75% of animal abusers
>   who did not commit offenses against the person. Therefore,
>   the findings simply support existing evidence that animal
>   cruelty, and particularly the deliberate infliction of unnecessary
>   physical pain or suffering, may occur in conjunction
>   with a wider range of antisocial behaviors.
>   Similar patterns of generalized criminality among animal
>   cruelty offenders have been noted in New South Wales,
>   Australia (Gullone and Clarke 2006). The range of criminal
>   behaviors performed by persons in New South Wales Police
>   databases with a record of animal abuse averaged four
>   different types of criminal offence. Assault, followed by
>   stealing, driving offences, and domestic violence were the
>   most common forms of crime committed by animal cruelty
>   offenders in New South Wales who had other criminal
>   charges. However, the New South Wales animal cruelty
>   offender statistics were not compared against a wider
>   sample of offenders without a history of animal cruelty.
>   Therefore, it cannot be concluded that patterns of generalized
>   criminal offending among animal cruelty offenders
>   differed from patterns of generalized criminal offending
>   either overall or among offenders who did not commit
>   animal cruelty.

McPhedran also critiques the lack of operational definition for animal cruelty in some of the research in this area.

And this is in fairly strong contrast with a paper by [Simmons et al. (2014)](https://doi.org/10.1080/10282580.2015.1093687), which although is not centered on [interpersonal] violence, does make pretty bold claims as to the predictive value of animal cruelty and appears to have decently large and representative samples:

> The objective of this study was to document the long-term relationship between youthful animal abuse and a variety of problem behavior outcomes later in life. Data were used from a national, longitudinal, and multigenerational sample collected by the National Youth Survey Family Study, which assessed families across 27 years from 1977 to 2004. The analytic sample consisted of 2538 individuals who were analyzed using multivariate ordinary least squares and logistic regression modeling that controlled for important demographic factors.  Hypotheses were tested across two generations separately showing that a history of animal abuse does, indeed, predict later problem behaviors, including serious offending, marijuana use, other drug use, alcohol use, and deviant beliefs. Depending on the outcome examined, each model accounts for 5–34% of the variation in respondents’ problem behaviors. Within each model, animal abuse was often one of the strongest predictors.

So what to conclude from all this? Low quality primary studies leave substantial leeway for investigators or reviewers to interpret the data according to their own predispositions or agendas. Also, since all these studies are observational, you can never rule out all confounders etc. What's the best predictor may depend on what you included or not in the model etc. So big grain of salt prescribed for the reader and perhaps more research needed.

Answer (score 11):

"Is there any evidence of a correlation?"

Yes. There are known common causes, and those are classified as [empathy disorders](http://www.suite101.com/content/empathy-a11170). [fMRI results](http://www.wattpad.com/816530-brainwaves-are-different-in-veg-ns-than-omnis) show that lack of empathy is a real, fundamental brain effect, and humans normally have empathy towards fellow humans as well as animals.

Now, that last result showed that empathy towards other people is not a good predictor for empathy towards animals. I can't obviously cite references for your particular case, but I expect you killed fish for food. That's another part of the brain, gathering food.

Comment: If I were being sceptical I'd say that isn't evidence of correlation. What it is is offering an explanation or cause for the correlation (i.e. that it's caused by "lack of empathy"), assuming that there is one. However +1 for offering a link which purports to study the relative empathy of omnivores/hunters: i.e. for trying to begin to address the 2nd-last paragraph of the OP.

Comment: I don't think your references answer the question. The first defines a rather circular concept - those without a property called empathy are diagnosable as having no empathy. That doesn't show a correlation. The second is a non-peer reviewed student paper about another article (why not cut out the middle man and read/cite the article directly?) about the differences in brain function between a subset of vegans, vegetarians and omnivores. That doesn't show a correlation between (directly) injuring animals and humans. You may be right, but you haven't shown us that you are.

Comment: "a real, fundamental brain effect" given that empathy is a kind of behaviour, clearly it is something to do with the brain. If fMRI can't detect a correlate with some form of behaiour does that mean its not "real"?

Comment: @Raedwald: No, that's faulty logic. You're confusing "sufficient" with "necessary".

Comment: I think that there is an important, unaddressed issue here. Do these low empathy types make up a large fraction of the "kids who do bad stuff to animals" population, or are kids just meaner than adults? Secondly is there a threshold effect at which many kids do some bad stuff, but only the ones who will grow up to be violent adults cross some level of cruelty or repetition?

Comment: Both links are now broken.

Comment: MSalters, you're missing @Raedwald's point. Empathy is a mental phenomenon; as such, there's no conceivable way that it would not be a "brain effect", all mental phenomena happen in the brain. Why does it then matter whether that effect can be detected by an fMRI scan? In what way is our understanding of empathy affected by the fact that we're able to detect it with a scanner? You seem to be arguing that the fact that empathy is detectable with a scanner is in itself evidence that empathy for humans and empathy for animals are correlated, but advance no argument whatsoever for why this is so.

Answer (score 6):

I quote the Wikipedia article on [psychopathy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychopathy#cite_ref-72)

> Three behaviors — bedwetting, cruelty to animals and firestarting, known as the **Macdonald triad** — were first described by J.M. MacDonald as possible indicators, if occurring together over time during childhood, of future episodic aggressive behavior. However, subsequent research has found that bedwetting is not a significant factor and the triad as a particular profile has been called an urban legend. Questions remain about a connection between animal cruelty and later violence, though it has been included in the DSM as a possible factor in conduct disorder and later antisocial behavior.

and the one on [Cruelty to animals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_cruelty#Psychological_disorders), which makes the interesting point that there may be a common cause to both (I think this runs somewhat counter to this "evil shows itself early" thing that I feel is associated with it)

> It has also been found that children who are cruel to animals have often witnessed or been victims of abuse themselves. In two separate studies cited by the Humane Society of the United States roughly one-third of families suffering from domestic abuse indicated that at least one child had hurt or killed a pet.

Unfortunately I don't have access to this [article](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1300/J460v02n04_04) though it promises to be a current review on the matter. This [one](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0272735800000660) I do have access to, they urgently call for more research, which may have happened in the meantime.